# Why would one need to use `MSG_WAITALL` FLAG instead of `0` FLAG? Why to use it with UDP?

Tags: sockets

At some point when coding sockets one will face the receive-family of functions ([`recv`, `recvfrom`, `recvmsg`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/2-recvfrom/)).

This function accepts a FLAG argument, in which I see that the `MSG_WAITALL` is used in many examples on the web, such as this [example on UDP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/?ref=lbp).

Here is a definition of the `MSG_WAITALL` flag

> MSG_WAITALL (since Linux 2.2)
>
> This flag requests that the operation block until the full request is satisfied. However, the call may still return less data than requested if a signal is caught, an error or disconnect occurs, or the next data to be received is of a different type than that returned. **This flag has no effect for datagram sockets**.

Hence, my two questions:

1. Why would one need to use `MSG_WAITALL` FLAG instead of `0` FLAG? (Could someone explain a scenario of a problem for which the use of this would be the solution?)
2. Why to use it with UDP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the quoted man page mentions, `MSG_WAITALL` has no effect on UDP sockets, so there's no reason to use it there.  Examples that do use it are probably confused and/or the result of several generations of cargo-cult/copy-and-paste programming.  :)

For TCP, OTOH, the default behavior of `recv()` is to block until *at least one byte of data* can be copied into the user's buffer from the sockets incoming-data-buffer.  The TCP stack will try to provide as many bytes of data as it can, of course, but in a case where the socket's incoming-data-buffer contains fewer bytes of data than the user has passed in to `recv()`, the TCP stack will copy as many bytes as it can, and return the byte-count indicating how many bytes it actually provided.

However, some people find would prefer to have their `recv()` call keep blocking until *all* of the bytes in their passed-in array have been filled in, regardless of how long that might take.  For those people, the `MSG_WAITALL` flag provides a simple way to obtain that behavior.  (The flag is not strictly necessary, since the programmer could always emulate that behavior by writing a `while()` loop that calls `recv()` multiple times as necessary, until all the bytes in the buffer have been populated... but it's provided as a convenience nonetheless)

Answer (score 0):

If you read data in records of known sizes from a TCP socket and you know that the next record will be 250 bytes, you may want to call `recv()` with a size of 250 bytes and use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag to ensure you either read the entire record or no record at all. Without that flag you may only read half of a record or only the first 10 bytes of a record. With that flag you will always get a full record or an error (all the other cases where you could still get less result in an error and can either be avoided entirely or mean that you will never get that full record ever).